# they are all happy VS they all are happy

Tags: grammar

1. They are all happy
2. They all are happy
3. All they are happy

What is the difference among them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1 and #2 are different.

#1 shows that they have only one emotion -- happiness.  They aren't also surprised.  There is no hint of wonderment.  They are completely, unabashedly, and identically happy.  The inclusion of every person is less clear, and may be contradicted.  The sentence is perhaps idiomatic.  Consider this: "The children were all giddy when the clown appeared, but not all of them.  Sam retreated to the rear wall, terrified."

#2 shows that all of them, everyone, is happy.  Happiness need not be exclusive or all-consuming.  For each of them, they are describable as happy.

#3 as it stands isn't grammatically complete.  If it were changed to "All they are is happy", it would be like #1, but with more emphasis.

Comment: The children were all giddy when the clown appeared, but not all of them. Sam retreated to the rear wall, terrified.   In this case, why not use all in the first part?

Comment: As an example of #1 usage, the emphasis is on their giddiness, not on the universality.

Comment: So, in the first sentence, 'all' just emphasis 'happy'. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, "all" emphasizes happy.

Comment: Okay. I know now.

Comment: In your opinion, this sentence should be right: They all are all happy. But I feel it weird.

Comment: As you suggest,  IMO it is correct,  and suggests the all of the individualls are completely consumed with happiness.   There may be an element of hyperbole in the statement, or an element of disbelief.

Comment: Why is there an element of hyperbole or disbelief? If I want to express all the people and impress all are happy, what should I say? Thanks.

Comment: I am a jaded, somewhat cynical, native English speaker.  I suggested an element of hyperbole or disbelief because when a cynical person such as myself presents something as 100+% undiluted happiness, they assuming that it will be disbelieved by a similar reader.  There is a "double positive" discussion on SE which I'm having trouble pasting with my phone. Too much praise or enthusiasm can cast a statement into doubt.

Comment: May you tell how to understand **All they are is happy**. I feel it weird. How to understand **All they are** and why used **is** here?

Comment: @Y. zeng, the question is a different.  "All they are is" is a wording to emphasize the dominance of what comes next.  "All they are" is a noun phrase.  "Is" reports the state of being. "Happy" reports that state.

Comment: It is not unlike other hyperbolic constructs that over-simplify human emotions or motivations, such as "All those people are is evil" or "all our children are angels".

Comment: Why not say: All our childer are is angels?

Comment: Have you met my children?  Just kidding.  One could say that, any to my ear it has some ironic meaning.

Comment: I just don't know why delete **is** in the sentence: All our childer are is angels.

Comment: To my ear the "all my children are is angels" excludes all other childish behavior, and could be a mild complaint.  "All my children are angels" seems like they are well behaved children most of the time, but they are still children.  The "all ... are is ..." construct seems to be to be very rigid and limiting, while "all ... are ... " construct is more open to other characteristics in addition.

Comment: **All they are happy** is wrong. **All our children are angels** is right. May you tell when should I include **is** after **All**?

Comment: This is becoming more of a discussion that should be moved outside the Q&A part of stackexchamge.  You are right that "all they are happy" is wrong, but I see the problem as being "all" with "they".  "All of them are happy" sounds better.  In the "are is" construct, "they" is the subject of "are", and "all" modifies "is".  In "all they are happy", "all" modifies "they", but it works better as "they are all happy".

Comment: So,is it right to say, 'All they are happy'?  It is right. Am I right? What about **They are all happy** vs **They all are happy**? Just because of emphasis different things?

Comment: Yes.  English is flexible about word order.  Often the meaning will change to emphasize different relationships within the sentence.  A classic example is to consider the sentence "I love you", and place the word "only" at every place.  "Only I love you". "I only love you". "I love only you". "I love you only".  These are different meanings.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Is **All they are happy** right too?

Answer (score 2):

1) This is the most correct one, grammatically.
2) This one is fine too.
3) Grammatically wrong. It would rather be **"All of them are happy"**.

There is no difference of meaning among all the 3 sentences.